# problem in set cookie and use proxy in vite react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, vite

In Vite ReactJS Ts APP when try to set cookie and use proxy it's not working properly in production nut in the localhost it's working fine

that's my code at vite.config.ts

```
const defaultConfig = {
  plugins: [
    react({ include: "**/*.tsx", }),
  ],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://tame-lime-rooster-tie.cyclic.app',
        changeOrigin: true,
        configure: (proxy, options) => {
          proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, res) => {
            if (!req.headers.cookie) {
              return;
            }
            console.log('req.headers.cookie', req.headers.cookie)
            proxyReq.setHeader('cookie', req.headers.cookie);
          });
        },
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
}

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  if (command === 'serve') {
    const isDev = mode === 'development';
    return {
      ...defaultConfig,
      server: {
        proxy: {
          '/api': {
            target: isDev ? 'http://localhost:5000' : 'https://tame-lime-rooster-tie.cyclic.app',
            changeOrigin: true,
            configure: (proxy, options) => {
              proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, res) => {
                if (!req.headers.cookie) {
                  return;
                }
                console.log('req.headers.cookie', req.headers.cookie)
                proxyReq.setHeader('cookie', req.headers.cookie);
              });
            },
            secure: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    return defaultConfig;
  }
});
```

but it's working good only on localhost when i deploy the app it's not working good

Comment: Based on what I can see, it appears you are trying to deploy your production server using the Vite development server. This is not considered a best practice. A good process, however, is to deploy this folder over an S3 & CDN (or any static serving service) as soon as the build process is complete (npm run build -> dist folder), and your server (`cyclic.app`) should support API calls from the static serving domain.
Ensure that your server (`cyclic.app`) response headers and static serving headers are handled correctly.